# Best way the parse an array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like some advices to optimise my PHP code, I'm using an API and sometime it return **one result** or **an array of results** like this :

**First possibility :**

```
Array
(
    [collection] => Array
        (
            [links] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 1
                   [url] => www.google.fr
                )              
        )
)
```

**or Second possibility :**

```
Array
(
    [collection] => Array
        (
            [links] => Array
                (
                   [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [url] => www.google.fr
                        )
                   [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [url] => www.google.fr
                        )
                   [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [url] => www.google.fr
                        )
                )              
        )
)
```

How can I optimise my code for this case ?

```
$url = '';
$nb_results = count($array['collection']['links']);

if($nb_results == 1){
    $url .= $array['collection']['links']['url'];
} else {
    foreach( $array['collection']['links'] as $r){
        $url .= $r['url'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If API returns only one result, make an array from this result and use foreach. Thanks to that you don't need to have use `if..else` when creating `$url` variable. Look at this code:

```
// checking if links is array; if not - make array with one returned element from API
$data = isset($array['collection']['links'][0]) ? $array['collection']['links'] : array($array['collection']['links']);

foreach( $data as $r)
{
    $url .= $r['url'].'<br />';
}
```